# Update a postgresQl table using typeorm and nest js

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using nest js to create API. When user is registered i use this `entity`

```js
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

After that using another endpoint that was created by me i want to add a new field in this table, like: `code`

```js
const updateUser = await this.usersRepository.update(email, {
  code: 'code example',
});
```

... but i get `TS2345: Argument of type '{ code: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<UserEntity>'.`. 
 Why i get this error and how to solve the issue adding a new field `code`?

Comment: You don't define a `code` column on the `User` entity, right?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, you are right. Is there a possibility to add a new field if that was not declared previously?

Comment: That's not how SQL works. To add a new column, you'd need to run a query. If you need a dynamic column, you can use a `JSON` column, or use NoSQL so you can add columns on the fly

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, in this context could you please help here? Will help me a lot. Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71454445/mongoose-additional-schema-field

Answer (score 1):

`this.usersRepository.update` is trying to typecast `{code: 'code example',}` as `UserEntity` and is failing as `code` is not an attribute defined in `UserEntity` class.

In TypeORM this can be fixed in either of the 2 ways:

**1. Using `synchronize:true` in your `createConnection` as in :**

```js
export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
    useFactory: async () => await createConnection({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [
          __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
      ],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  },
];
```

And add [1] :

```
@Column()
code:string
```

to `UserEntity`

**2. Alter command on db**

Run an alter query on your SQL DB and add a column of code in the `user` table.
Also, add code column in your UserEntity as mentioned in [1] above.

Anyways you have to start by fixing the UserEntity Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeorm` [`queryRunner.addColumn`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d61f857ce9447a25d074810759fd5c4aad9a08e3/src/query-runner/QueryRunner.ts#L273) for this purpose.

Example:

```
import { getConnection, TableColumn } from "typeorm";

const connection = getConnection();

await connection.createQueryRunner().addColumn(
  "tablename",
  new TableColumn({
    name: "code",
    type: "varchar",
  })
);

// OR With TypeOrm Repository

this.usersRepository.queryRunner.addColumn(
  "tablename",
  new TableColumn({
    name: "code",
    type: "varchar",
  })
);
```

Additionally, you can also many other functions from `queryRunner` like bellow ones which can help you.

- `hasTable`
- `hasColumn`
- `renameTable`
- `renameColumn`
- `changeColumn`
- ... many others [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d61f857ce9447a25d074810759fd5c4aad9a08e3/src/query-runner/QueryRunner.ts#L22).